# How exactly does the MenuInflater work?

Tags: java, android

If I get it right this far, MenuInflater is a type of object that can inflate (blow up, expand?) a Menu type object.
But when is the method called and which Menu object is automatically passed in?
What does getMenuInflater() do (or is it just another way of ... = new MenuInflater())?
And then once the inflater object is created, what exactly does the .inflate do?
What does the passed-in menu object do with my main.xml menu?

*(I'm sorry if I'm asking too many questions at once.)*

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu);
}
```

Comment: Just read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Of course I have read that before, but it only says this about the java part: "To specify the options menu for an activity, override onCreateOptionsMenu() (fragments provide their own onCreateOptionsMenu() callback). In this method, you can inflate your menu resource (defined in XML) into the Menu provided in the callback. For example:" and then an example similar to the one I've given above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `MenuInflater` is an object that is able to create `Menu` from xml resources (of course only menus resources), that is : construct a new instance of `Menu` given a menu resource identifier.

The `onCreateOptionMenu(Menu)` is called when the menu button of the device is pressed, or either `Activity.openOptionsMenu()` is called.

The actual rendering of the menu is handled by the activity. Just before it is shown, the `Activity` passes to you the menu so that you can fill it with your own items, then shows it.
So Android undertakes that since it's not your business to render the menu, you shall not control what menu is actually passed to you inside `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

---

As for the `ActionBar`, the `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called when filling `ActionBar`, so that options from the menu be available in the `ActionBar`. This method is only called once after the `Activity` be created. If you want to modify the menu later, you should instead override `Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu`

Comment: And with the menu button, you mean the 3 dots in the right of the action bar, right?

Comment: That's it : on some devices the menu button might not be a physical button, so the action bar include an overflow button that shows the options menu

Comment: Okay so (correct me if I'm wrong): I press the overflow button (an object of type Menu) which calls the onCreateOptionsMenu and passes itself as an argument. Then a MenuInflater is created which inflates the main.xml into the overflow menu. And finally some necessary super data is returned for the menu to actually work.

Comment: The actual behavior is : You press the button as said. This button isn't a `Menu`, just a button. The `Activity` is notified and calls `onCreateOptionsMenu` if it was already maid, then `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Both functions receive the `MenuInflater` of the `Activity` (see `Activity.getMenuInflater`) and a `Menu` object that's passed by the activity (it's creation isn't covered by the API).

Comment: Then you fill the `Menu` inflating xml resources if necessary and the method returns. The `Activity` then takes the `Menu` it passed to you, and which you filled and displays it (how isn't covered by the API).

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Yeah it's kind of weird why the API doesn't cover this, I can't be the only new developer who wonders how this works ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

My understanding about "inflating" is "reading" a resource file (a XML file which describes a layout or GUI element) and "creating" the actual objects that correspond to it; this will make the menu object visible within an Android application.
[MenuInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html) class represents an Android framework class specialized in parsing and constructing menus from menu resource files.

Have a look at: [Build Menus in Android with Java and XML: Introduction](http://www.sitepoint.com/menus-in-android/)

From the article:

> Once the menu resource file (my_menu.xml) is ready and has all the
>   items you intend to add, you can use MenuInflater to override the
>   function onCreateOptionsMenu. This function is supposed to fill the
>   menu object with the desired menu items, but Android’s MenuInflater
>   class helps you create menu items from the XML resource mentioned
>   above